# Crystal Report Prompts for variables issue in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I have a report in which the set parameter value is set but when I run the script it always prompts for the value of the parameter. Here is the code I used:

```
Customer_List1.SetParameterValue("IsSubs", subs);
Customer_List1.Database.Tables["Customer_List"].SetDataSource((DataTable)dt);
crv_customer_list.ReportSource = Customer_List1;
crv_customer_list.Refresh();
```

Customer_List1 is the report and crv_customer_list is the crystalreportviewer

I have used similar code in another form of the same project, It works absolutely fine there. Please do help with this

Comment: My 2 cents. I am not sure, but why do you have setparameter statement before setDatasource and reportSource? Wouldnt that come 3rd in the code.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot! Its working. Sorry I didn't knew that earlier.

Comment: Thats great..Shall I add it as the answer than? That will give me some brownie points too

Comment: Oh Yes!!! That was my solution.

Comment: Done. You can now mark it as answer. Thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in comments, writing the solution as an answer.

The sequence of statements is your problem.  You are setting parameter values before initialization. The correct sequence should be:

```
Customer_List1.Database.Tables["Customer_List"].SetDataSource((DataTable)dt);
crv_customer_list.ReportSource = Customer_List1;
Customer_List1.SetParameterValue("IsSubs", subs);    
crv_customer_list.Refresh();
```